# How to change UI title in PowerShell when starting a new process

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use the `Start-Process` cmdlet in PowerShell to run a PS script in a new window with a title that identifies which script is running. For example, I'd like to run my `SpeedTest.ps1` script in a window titled "Speed Test". After reading through the many answers for similar questions, I thought this would be a simple task. However, it just does not seem to work. My PS code is:

```
$host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Speed Test"
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList .\SpeedTest.ps1
```

The script runs in a new window as expected, but the title of the window is "Windows PowerShell" and not "Speed Test". I verified the `WindowTitle` variable was set to "Speed Test", but can't figure out why the window title won't change. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the statement that changes the window title part of the command string that you pass to the `powershell.exe` executable, via `-c` / `-Command` (which is implied in Windows PowerShell, whereas PowerShell [Core] v6+ now defaults to `-File`):

```
Start-Process powershell '-c "$host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = \"Speed Test\"; .\SpeedTest.ps1"'
```

<sup>Note: Since you know you're starting a new *console* window, you could use the more concise `[Console]::Title = ...`</sup>

Note that since PowerShell isn't the fastest to start up, it'll take a bit before the window title changes; the following technique, which uses `cmd.exe`'s internal `start` command, changes the window title right away, but note that the new window's colors will be those of `cmd.exe`, not of PowerShell:

```
cmd /s /c 'start "Speed Test" powershell.exe -file .\SpeedTest.ps1'
```

Comment: Along the lines of mklement0's answer you could alternatively include the [Console]::Title= statement in your SpeedTest.ps1 script.

Answer (score 2):

You can change by **`$host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle`**  and write your `title` between double quotation for example:

> **`$host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Hello from powershell"`**